# TF: how to create a dataset from user input data

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I've started recently to play with tensorflow and, more specifically, with the new dataset API.
I've successfully used a dataset to feed training data to my simple model by plugging dataset's iterators to the nodes of my graph representing input and label. Something like:

```
input = input_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next() 
label = label_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
```

Now I'm wondering what to do when I have to do inference on a user input, that is, the user gives me one single input value and I have to make my prediction. If I had a placeholder I would just put the user input in a feed_dict, but with the dataset api I have very little idea how to do something similar. Shall I have a separate graph only for inference in which my `input` variable is a placeholder?

I've tried already to make a feedable iterator as described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets) but that only works with a placeholder for strings, while my input are int32.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

For that specific purpose, tensorflow provides `tf.placeholder_with_default` API

```
# Create a Dataset
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((input_dataset, label_dataset)).batch(32).repeat(...)

# Create Iterator
input, label = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

# Create Placholders
x = tf.placeholder_with_default(input, shape=[...], name='input')
y = tf.placeholder_with_default(label, shape-[...], name='label')

def nn_model(features, labels):
    logits = ...    
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=labels, logits=logits))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01).minimize(loss)
    return optimizer, loss

# Create Model
train_op, loss_op = nn_model(x, y)

# Training
sess.run(train_op)

# Inference
sess.run(logits, feed_dict={x:..., y:...})
```